# Inversion count using merge sort: Why must I copy the temp array back into the original array in the merge subroutine?

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

I was looking at a piece of code on the web for inversion count using merge sort. The merge subroutine in the code takes two arrays as parameters, including arr[], the original array whose inversions need to be counted, and a temp array used for the sorting. But the only thing that the merge part actually returns is the number of inversions between the two arrays (it doesn't return an array). There's a for loop at the end of the subroutine that copies all of the values of the temp array back into the array arr[], so that arr[] becomes merged. The program only works correctly with this for loop, but I can't see why. Don't both of the arrays passed as arguments fall out of scope when the method returns? How does it affect anything to have arr[] change at the very end of the subroutine?

```
  static long mergeSort(int arr[], int array_size)
    {
        int temp[] = new int[array_size];
        return _mergeSort(arr, temp, 0, array_size - 1);
    }

    static long _mergeSort(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right)
    {
        int mid = 0;
        long inv_count = 0;
        if (right > left) {

            mid = (right + left) / 2;


            inv_count = _mergeSort(arr, temp, left, mid);
            inv_count += _mergeSort(arr, temp, mid + 1, right);

            inv_count += merge(arr, temp, left, mid + 1, right);
        }
        return inv_count;
    }

 
    static long merge(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int mid, int right)
    {
       int i = left;
       int k = left;
       int j = mid;
       long mergeInvCount = 0;

       while (i < mid && j <= right) {
           if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
               temp[k++] = arr[i++];
           } else {
               temp[k++] = arr[j++];
               mergeInvCount = mergeInvCount + mid - i;
           }
       }
     while(i < mid) {
         temp[k++] = arr[i++];
           }
     while(j <= right) {
         temp[k++] = arr[j++];
       }
/* I don't get what this code is doing:*/
        for (i = left; i <= right; i++) {
            arr[i] = temp[i];
        }
         return mergeInvCount;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int coolArray[] = {5, 78, 2, 34, 56, 23, 45, 2, 65, 4, 2, 4};
        System.out.println(mergeSort(coolArray, 12));
    }
}
```

The code I'm confused about is near the bottom, below the comment.
Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: The copy back can be avoided by doing a one time allocation of a temp array, then alternating the direction of merge with each level of recursion. A one time copy is done in this [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to deal with but in any case you'd require some extra space.

1. Either create temporary left and right subarray and make changes in the original array while sorting, Or
2. The one used here, use a temporary array apply merge sort over it and copy the values back in the original array. Because if we won't copy back to the original array (the subarray will remain unsorted in the original array and hence when we will apply the merge on it, the inversions will be different than the actual count).

An alternate and perhaps, less confusing approach is the following one:

```
private static int mergeAndCount(int[] arr, int l, int m, int r) 
{ 

    int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, l, m + 1); 
    int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, m + 1, r + 1); 

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = l, swaps = 0; 

    while (i < left.length && j < right.length) { 
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) 
            arr[k++] = left[i++]; 
        else { 
            arr[k++] = right[j++]; 
            swaps += (m + 1) - (l + i); 
        } 
    } 
    return swaps; 
} 

private static int mergeSortAndCount(int[] arr, int l, int r) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 

    if (l < r) { 
        int m = (l + r) / 2; 

        count += mergeSortAndCount(arr, l, m); 

        count += mergeSortAndCount(arr, m + 1, r); 

        count += mergeAndCount(arr, l, m, r); 
    } 

    return count; 
}
```